# Why is quick sort better than counting sort?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, quicksort, counting-sort

Quick sort:

- worst case o(n^2)
- average case O(nlogn)

Counting sort:

- in all cases o(n)

Both quick sort and counting sort are stable algorithms.

If these two conditions are present, why is quick sort still better than counting sort?

Comment: Did you check the constraints of counting sort? I mean what are the pre-conditions upon which you can run counting sort?

Comment: Who says that quicksort is better?

Comment: The two `n` are different `n`s.

Comment: [Quick sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is not normally regarded as a stable sort.  There are major constraints on the types that [Counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) can sort.

Comment: @jonathan leffler By stable you mean reliable?

Comment: @machine_1: 'stable' with respect to sorting has a specific meaning, namely that if two entries being compared compare equal, then they will be present in the sorted result in the same relative order that they were in before the sort started.  Quick sort is perfectly reliable; it is not stable.  (See the Wikipedia link in my previous comment — it specifies that Quick sort is not stable. It also has a link to information about what constitutes a stable sort.)

Comment: This question was judged unduly harshly. It is a reasonable question with a reasonable answer. Any complaint about “better” being an opinion could have been dealt with by editing.

Comment: Count sort is not cache friendly at all. A decent generic count sort usually has a counting array in MBs. The CPU cache may not even be able to fit that much data and as the chances of hitting any index in the count array is pretty random, you will continuously keep having cache misses.

Comment: There's a third option, [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), which has linear time complexity related to k*n, where k is the number of passes needed for radix sort. For example, 32 bit integers sorted 8 bits at a time would take 4 passes. Usually radix sort is implemented least significant field first, since the fields can be logically concatenated after each pass.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sorts aren't always necessarily 'better' than one another. In certain situations, quicksort might be preferred for a number of reasons:

1. Quicksort is in place, unlike counting sort, which has to create a number of arrays (e.g. use more memory) to do its work.
2. It may seem like counting sort is O(n), but take a look at the intermediate counting array that has to be created. The counting array length is essentially the difference between the largest and smallest elements in your original array. If the range is really big, this counting array is massive. For example, what if your array only has two elements, but the two elements are 1 and 9999999? And this counting array has to be processed (all that summation and counting stuff). So really, the run time of counting sort is O(n+k) where k is the difference between the largest and smallest elements in the original array.
3. Finally, counting sort seems...difficult to implement if the elements you're trying to sort are not numbers. How would it work for strings?

Comment: Succinctly, counting sort wouldn't work on general arbitrary-length strings.

Comment: thanks 2nd point is satisfying thanks a lot

Comment: `k` can be considered to be the number of distinct elements as opposed to the range of elements, but it is rare for the number of distinct elements to be greatly smaller than the range (such as the example of two distinct elements with values 1 and 9999999), and mapping would be needed to convert element values into a mapped index.